# Grails - Data Binding One to One Association Not Working

Tags: grails, data-binding, associations, one-to-one, grails-domain-class

I'm trying to do a straight forward data bind that involved two domain classes in a one to one association.  Here's the two classes:

```
class Request
{
  static hasOne = [form: Form]

  Form form
}

class Form
{
  static belongsTo = [request: Request]

  String string
}
```

I then do the following data binding (this is to demonstrate the problem ... the real data bind comes from a form):

```
Request request = new Request()
request.properties = ['form.string': 'string value']
```

However, I end up with a Request object that has a null form property instead of a Request object that has a Form object for its form property along with the string value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem wasn't with the actual classes, but the map being passed to the data binding.  Even though according to the Grails documentation the following should have worked:

```
Request request = new Request()
request.properties = ['form.string': 'string value']
```

it doesn't.  However, if I change the map to be I get proper binding:

```
Request request = new Request()
request.properties = [form: [string: 'string value']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
class Request
{
  Form form
}

class Form
{
  static belongsTo = [request: Request]

  String string
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that makes no difference, still the same problem.

Comment: If you are using a persistent database you will need to generate the migration for this change. You are defining the form attribute twice, "static hasOne = [form: Form]" define the attribute, you don't need to add "Form form" below. If that dosn't work, try adding static mappedBy = [ form: 'none'] to the Request class (this will also generate a migration)

Comment: I created two classes identical to your example and re-created all tables in the database (so no worries about migration) and unfortunately still the same issue.  The form object never gets created by the binding.  I also tried your idea of adding mappedBy and still the same problem.

Comment: I face a similar problem using request as a instance name i changed for something like req and its began working